# What could I do if I don't agree with my edit rollback?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, rollbacks

What could I do if I strongly disagree with the rollback without any comment from another user?
What actions can I take? What is the best way?

Should I simply do rollback to my edit and be happy?

I am asking in general but here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21917262/revisions).

Comment: That edit did not add a lot of value to the post. I can understand disagreeing with having an edit rolled back but there's no good reason to have strong feelings about it in this case.

Comment: I thought that my edit was mainly about tags and title, so I was surprised, especially after it was approved.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a [long and storied history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) of bad suggested edit approvals.

Comment: Hm, seems like I paid too much attention to title and tags.

Comment: +1 for asking this question here and being willing to learn

Comment: @Fyodor the tags in the title in that fashion are less objectionable than they are when appended to the front.  For example "C#: How do I Foo the Bar" is bad, but "How do I Foo the Bar in C#" is a little better and doesn't necessarily have to be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out, things are much clearer to me now :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your specific example, the rollback was 100% correct.

The edit that you "like" added a lot of horrendous formatting that is unneeded and strongly discouraged.  Code markup via backticks are not for highlighting key parts, they are for code.

However, you were working from guidance in [Is there a page that explains how inline code spans should and should not be used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215472/is-there-a-page-that-explains-how-inline-code-spans-should-and-should-not-be-use/215595#215595).  There are 2 issues that I have here,

- First is don't do it too much.  If someone is using the same class name over and over, it is not necessary to highlight every single occurrence, as it makes it more difficult to read the post.  (this is just my personal opinion though)
- More importantly, if you are highlighting a class name, make sure you are highlighting the class name and it is spelled correct (as it appears in the documentation)

In your edit, `webbrowser` made it look like you were editing to highlight a "key term" and not the name of the class.  The actual name of the class is `WebBrowser`.  Rejecting an edit (or rolling one back) because of capitalization can seem a bit nit-picky, but it is one of those things that can change the meaning of code in case-sensitive languages like C#.

But in general, if you do not approve of any edit (whether it is a regular edit or a rollback), you can roll it back yourself.  However **do not** do it more than once.  You are basically getting into an edit war with someone and it will automatically get flagged for a moderator.  Instead of someone is continually editing a post in a manner you disagree with, then just flag it for a moderator, explain the situation, and let them deal with it.

Comment: So in general case it's better to treat it like a rejected edit and think about how to make better edit?

Comment: @Fyodor for this case yes.  You got the +2 that you shouldn't have, but learn from the rollback.  It would have been nice of the editor who rolled back your edit left you a comment explaining why, but at least it prompted you to ask here.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I read few posts about formatting [like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215472/is-there-a-page-that-explains-how-inline-code-spans-should-and-should-not-be-use/215595#215595) and there are advices to use backticks to highlight inline control, class, method names. So I am confused. Will it be better to highlight only first occurrence to avoid "horrendous formatting"?

Comment: @Fyodor Well, in general, that guidance is correct, but if the same class and method is used often, I don't think you want to overdo it.  The code formatting is not the easiest in terms of readability.  But for the specific edit, the name of the class is `WebBrowser`, not `webbrowser` so it really doesn't appear as if it is the name of a class and instead looks like you are highlighting a key term.

Comment: Thanks again for the valuable notices! From now my edits will be even more intelligent I suppose :)