# Which Markdown formatting should be used for a filename of code?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I often want to write filenames for code.

Normally I write like this:

#### Filename

```
string = "This is example code"
```

Is this okay? Is there a standard Stack Overflow way of Markdown formatting for writing a filename?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215472/is-there-a-page-that-explains-how-inline-code-spans-should-and-should-not-be-use

Comment: File names can be long and contain dots that might be confused with punctuation, and spaces, as sometimes happens in MS Windows. (Whole file paths can even contain slashes and colons.) Inline code style can prevent the such file names from blending in with surrounding sentence and thereby ruining it. For example: This is a sentence containing a file named `oh this name has spaces.and.dots` which may be hard to read without the file in inline code style. Italics or bold don't solve the problem well since they don't "bind" the parts of the file name as closely as the code style box.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is ok if you write it the way you shown (the filename on one line, then on other lines code following). But if you have something like this:

> In my viewcontroller.h I have:
>
> ```
> some code there
> ```

I personally would like to see it as

> In my `viewcontroller.h` I have:
>
> ```
> some code there
> ```

Comment: So `viewcontroller.h` is the name of the method here as indicated by the code formatting?

Comment: @rand no... it is just a bit unreadable without codformatting.

Comment: What is the actual markdown syntax to create example 2?

Comment: Click [edit] and see yourself, @Kurt :)

Answer (score 29):

#### Update

[Since July 2021 (apparently)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/578924#359977:%7E:text=July%202021) the previous method no longer works. Here's a new method based on tag stripping:

````html
<h5 a><strong><code>hello_world.js</code></strong></h5>

``` js
alert("Hello world!");
```
````

Here the `<h5 a>` tag gets stripped leaving its content "naked". Note that an attribute in `<h5 a>` tag and a blank line after it are required!

#### Original answer

You can make a very nice-looking named code block using small headers and inline code, like so:

````
#### **`hello_world.js`**
``` js
alert("Hello world!");
```
````

> **`hello_world.js`**
>
> ```js
> alert("Hello world!");
> ```

I've accidentally found it in [this post on Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327695/578924) and just don't want this great trick to get lost there as I was unsuccessfully looking for this some time before.

---

Though not as good as above, you could also specify a file name via language-specific comment before your code:

```bash
# hello_world.sh
echo "Hello world!"
```

Comment: it seems to produce ``<blockquote>  <code>code.js</code>  <pre>...</pre>  </blockquote>``

Comment: @myrdd: Not sure what you mean. Blockquote was added by the author, the code produces what's *inside* blockquote.

Comment: Related question and an answer by me explaining, why this seems no be no good idea: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327657/364003

Comment: @EvgenKo423 it's simply the HTML code corresponding to the Markdown code (`####` + `\`\`\``)

Comment: love it, but would be great to have something easy to remember and fast to type :)

Comment: Please don't abuse header markup like this. The number of `#` symbols in front of a line should correspond with the overall structure of the answer (although there is an argument for never using a single `#` since that is for H1 formatting, and some believe this should only apply to the question title - personally, I think it equally makes sense for the `N answers` label that's part of the page template, but....), and not simply be chosen for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Don't worry, no headers have been abused during writing of this answer. =)) Both of these methods don't/didn't result in any headers being generated, they are/were just removed from the markup (level 4+ headers were not supported previously, with a `#` at least). This is needed to prevent the `<code>` tag from being wrapped with a `<p>` tag which has bottom padding. I would happily use the official method if there was one... [1/2]

Comment: Even if the headers _would be_ generated, I think it would still correspond to the structure as they use small headers for small sections (IMO, if headers are needed, they should be added starting from smaller ones).
Take a look at the link by MEE above as well for more of my arguments. [2/2]

Answer (score 6):

I'd never thought about it until seeing [nicael's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246900/which-markdown-formatting-should-be-used-for-a-filename-of-code/246902#246902), but I kind of like "quoting the file".

> test.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
> setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
> set argument1=!%1!
> echo %argument1%>test.txt
> ```

---

> file2.bat
>
> ```
> @echo off
> echo %~1
> ```

Comment: And why posting a new answer, just to repeat what other user answered?

Comment: He wasn't literally recommending using quotes.  I am.

Answer (score 3):

After pounding my own head against my desk (and many others' desks) from [wondering about this four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350176/405046), I'm now writing all my Markdown with files as `code` because...

1. We indeed need to know when we are working with code-related things or with ideas outside of `code`; files are part of `code`.
2. In Unix & Linux, [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

- If it is Unix/Linux `code`, then it is already a file.
- Nearly all commands in Unix & Linux are actually files anyway (except `cd` and a few others).
- There really isn't a difference between Unix/Linux files and commands except **execution permissions**.
- If an executable command file is written with `code`, then all other non-executable files should also.

3. Files outside code get messed-up with underscore (`_`), which many files have in their names.

- Markdown renders more than one underscore `_` as an *italics-string* (literally `_italics-string_` in Markdown).
- This never causes a problem if file names are in backticks.

Comment: See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215472/578924) as well for more arguments on formatting file names and using `inline code` in general.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to do something like:

`requirements.txt`:

```
elasticsearch==7.0.0
elasticsearch-dsl==7.0.0
```

Answer (score -5):

Bolding is fine, though I think that the header markup you've used may be a little too forceful. Large text could help, though, if you had a lot of (hopefully small!) snippets in your post. I'm not sure we need a standard for this: use what makes your post most easily read and understood.

I will say, however, that code markup is definitely not the proper choice. The name of a file is not an element of a program; marking it as such is **semantically incorrect**.

Comment: "code markup is definitely not the proper choice" - it is hard to read completely unformatted complex file names with extensions when embedded inline, not the file name on one line and nothing else on this line

Comment: The name of the files are definitely elements of the program - If `ArrayUtils.java` isn't the name for a class of utility methods for arrays, the asker is doing it wrong. `main.js`, `static.js`, etc.

Comment: The currently-chosen formatting is not a justification for markup abuse, @nicael.

Comment: They are not _executable code_ in themselves, @Unihedro.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Should XML files of an Android project not be wrapped in code formatting then? They may be part of the program (an essential one), but are not executable.

Comment: What part of a filename is code unless it's used in the code? @uni

Comment: @random: I never said or implied that they are code, just that they are indeed elements of a program, contrary to what Josh attempted to bring otherwise.

Comment: So are we or are we not talking about semantics? @uni

Comment: XML is parsed by another program and interpreted, @Unihedro. A bare filename is not.

Comment: @random: Elements of a program are formatted with `\`inline code\``, so includes standard input, test cases, relevant directories and file names and executables and constants and related configurations. I do it, and I see everyone else do it, and I teach new users to use the site by leaving a comment about using inline styles instead of italics, and they agree. Not sure what being parsed takes significance here, @Josh. Perhaps `python2` myprogram.py `foo bar`...

Comment: Context matters. https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ But why would anyone think italics, which are used for titles or section headings, is first before bold on filenames? @uni

Comment: @random Your linked article formatted "Keep in mind that your key may also be named `id_dsa.pub`, `id_ecdsa.pub` or `id_ed25519.pub`" inline with code formatting, that's what I meant because it's related to a keyfile. As for using italics for filenames, I guess they used a "traditional" BBCode forum with no code formatting ever, but I can't be sure.

Comment: The link shows two ways to format filenames. Unformatted when used in text, formatted as code when shown as part of an output or parameter. @uni

Comment: @jscs "XML is parsed by another program and interpreted, Unihedro. A bare filename is not". - No, it is parsed. When you compile a program, the build system goes through all files in the project and does whatever is appropriate for them, and uses their names to identify the files. So, for example, in a C# WPF program the build system will go through .cs files and compile them, and go through the resource files and copy them to the output folder.